# Is there a word for a person that can do impossible things?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word for a person that can do impossible things? For example a person that can walk on water. And not magician.

Comment: Jesus and/or superman.

Comment: YHWH (pronounced, possibly, Yah' way), the tetragrammaton for the English word, Jehovah.

Comment: @rhetorician Actually, Jehovah is a "proper" name (and a likely [translation error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehovah#Discourses_rejecting_Jehovah)).  A Dictionary of the Bible (1863), William Robertson Smith summarized these discourses, concluding that "whatever, therefore, be the true pronunciation of the word, there can be little doubt that it is not Jehovah".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Thank you for your comment. True enough, Jehovah IS a proper name. Notice, however, I did not say Jehovah was pronounced Yah' way, but that the Tetragrammaton, YHWH, the vowel-less transliteration of the Hebrew word (and subsequently a vocalization of that word) ,יהוה the proper name of the God of Israel, which is (possibly) pronounced Yah' way (or strangely enough, possibly even Yah' hoo!!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. *Superhuman*, a human with extraordinary and unusual capabilities enabling them to perform feats well beyond anything that an ordinary person could conceivably achieve.

Comment: 'Miracle worker' has probably achieved compound-noun status and hence is arguably a single word.

Comment: If a superhuman is a human that can do extraordinary and unusual capabilities, then these human beings do exist. The OP's question is not really answered because he was pertaining to humans that can do "impossible" things, which cannot happen, since it is "impossible". Therefore, since it cannot happen, these humans do not also exist. No one can walk on water. "Superhuman" is not the answer. The superhumans' capabilities are still within possibilities.

Comment: @Lester no. Superhuman is impossible. See superman and other superheroes. That is why batman is explicitly not super powered.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If we are talking about fictional characters, then yes, it is indeed superhuman. But if we are talking about the reality, which I understood in OP's question, then superhuman is not the answer. I've just read the superhuman article in Wikipedia. I've learned that there are real people who possess extraordinary capabilities. Please correct me if my arguments are wrong.

Comment: @Lester if they truly have superhuman abilities then they're eligible for the [JREF Challenge](http://www.randi.org/site/index.php/1m-challenge.html). $1,000,000 says they don't. You seem to focus on the first part of the sentence, and skip over "well beyond anything that an ordinary person could conceivably achieve".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So the "naturally superhuman people" stated in Wikipedia should not be there? I know that they have physical abilities that *seem* superhuman. But, in the true sense of the word, they are *not* really superhumans. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Lester Correct. They may well be remarkable, exceptional or unbelievable. But they aren't "superhuman" (supernatural is an oxymoron). Also, from the wikipedia entry you cite - "that **seem** superhuman," I added the bold.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I quote "that an *ordinary* person could conceivably achieve". I think that's why the word "ordinary" is put there, because there *are* extraordinary human beings. It should have said "...that a person could conceivably achieve".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Okay now I understand.

Comment: @Lester - The O.P. has provided very little elaboration, but I would have no problem calling someone who could "walk on water" _superhuman_. I also think superhumans _can_ exist – in a metaphorical sense, at least. If someone wanted to speak of Usain Bolt's "superhuman speed," for example, I wouldn't correct them on a hairsplitting technicality, I'd simply enjoy the colorful hyperbole.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [omnipotent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/omnipotent).

An omnipotent being would essentially be a god to us, capable of doing things beyond what mortals can.

If you break it down, "omni" is a prefix for "all" and "potent" is that which possesses power.

Comment: Superhuman is a better choice, although omnipotent includes superhuman, it is likely enough to be superhuman to be seen to do impossible things

Answer (score 1):

No person, animal, or other entity can do 'impossible things' as 'impossible things' are impossible (1. Incapable of having existence or of occurring.). Not even gods, superhumans, or omnipotents.

The answer should be *oxymoron*.

Comment: "Red Dwarf: Waiting for God (#1.4)" (1988)

Lister: "I am your god."
The Cat: "Okay."
[points at his bowl of Crispies]
The Cat: "Turn this into a woman."
Lister: "I'm serious."
The Cat: "So am I."

Comment: -1 for being a smarta$$.  +1 for being a smarta$$ :)

Answer (score 0):

*Godlike*

This word seems perfect for what you want, especially as you mentioned "walking on water" and "not a magician".

Answer (score 0):

Supernatural-- defying the known laws of physics-- would be best.

Comment: Supernatural-- defying the known laws of physics-- would be best.

Comment: if you edit your answer to include your comment, I think your answer would be the best here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Often in English, one can coin a new word when no word exists that precisely conveys the meaning.

If you're not happy with using *superhuman* for example, based on where you're using it, you could try something like *homo impossibilis*! :-)